# Can I "brace" with an Integrated Weapon?

Tags: weapons, dark-heresy-1e

I have an Integrated Lathe Las-Rifle in my arm, and as a Crimson Guard, I have purchased a few upgrades to assist by Ranged ability. (Sights, aiming implants etc.).

However, the idea of "bracing" with an integrated weapon seems a bit obscure. Is it possible?

Comment: this is dark-heresy 2nd edition right?

Comment: @A0o Not entirely sure of the edition sorry

Comment: Crimson guard and lathe weapon probably mean 1st edition as this is from the "Lathes World" book.

Comment: @A0o yes, I can now confirm 1e. Sorry for the delay!

Comment: In this case ShadowKras answer is perfectly correct. Don't forget to accept answer if it is good for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bracing** is an action to ready a weapon, so it can be fired without penalties.

From the corebook (p. 127):

> Heavy weapons always require two hands and **must be braced** in some way, usually either on a bipod or tripod but equally it could be a windowsill or sandbag (or the firer’s shoulder in the case of RPG launchers), to be fired without penalties.

These penalties are descripted few lines above, on Heavy Weapons:

> Firing a heavy weapon without bracing incurs a **–30 penalty to hit** and prohibits Semi-Auto and Full Auto fire.

With the exception of the Lascannon (Heavy) and Laspistol (Pistol), all Las weapons are *Basic*, which do not require bracing nor gain any benefit from the Bracing action.

### Can I “brace” with an Integrated Weapon?

If it's a **Heavy Weapon**, yes, you have to use the *Bracing* action or take a -30 penalty to hit.

Comment: Well, in this case, my Integrated Las-Rifle is not considered a Heavy weapon. You have stated that certain weapons *require* the bracing actions to avoid penalties, but since the Las-Rifle *does not* require a bracing action, can I still "brace" with it?

Comment: There is no penalty with your ILS, so why brace it? It's to benefit from a talent?

Comment: RAW, no. You cannot benefit from bracing on anything other than heavy weapons.